# iframe auto resize in aspx files with vb.net codebehind

Tags: vb.net, iframe, asp.net

I put in the iframe tag as follows in my .aspx page -

Now what code do i put in javascript or vb.net to make this auto resizable depending on the size of the page that comes in?

Comment: the code was swallowed, you need to html-encode &gt; and &lt; tags.  You need to bind to the load event for the iframe, and check against the content document's height and width.  The down side is, I've found this to be unreliable.  Also, if the inner document is from another domain, you won't be able to auto-resize at all.

Answer (score 0):

From [Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/iframe-height-scrollbar-example/)

```
window.onload = function(){

  var child = document.getElementById('child-iframe-id');
  child.style.height = child.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';

}
```

NOTE: If your child content window comes from a different domain as the parent, this likely won't work correctly, or reliably.